# jQuery unbind or remove fadeIn fadeOut?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a div to fade in or out when the window has been resized to a certain size (below 960px width), and the user clicks on a button that reveals another div so that they don't overlap at low screen sizes. This is working:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    if ( jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
        jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});

        jQuery('#tblcontents').toggle(function() {
            jQuery(".main").fadeOut(1000);
        }, function(){ 
            jQuery(".main").fadeIn(1000);
            jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});
        });
    }
});

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 960) {
        jQuery(".main").stop(true, true);
    }
});
```

But my problem arises when the user then re sizes the window to above 960px the fadeIn and fadeOut remains active, how do i solve this?
I have tried the above example along with this:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    if ( jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
        jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});

        jQuery('#tblcontents').toggle(function(){
            jQuery(".main").fadeOut(1000);
        }, function(){ 
            jQuery(".main").fadeIn(1000);
            jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});
        });
    } else {
        jQuery(".main").stop(true, true);
    }

});
```

and this:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    if ( jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
        jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});

        jQuery('#tblcontents').toggle(function(){
            jQuery(".main").fadeOut(1000);
        }, function(){ 
            jQuery(".main").fadeIn(1000);
            jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});
        });
    } else {
        jQuery(".main").finish();
    }
});
```

along with this:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
        jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});

        jQuery('#tblcontents').toggle(function(){
            jQuery(".main").fadeOut(1000);
        }, function(){ 
            jQuery(".main").fadeIn(1000);
            jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});
        });
    } else {
        jQuery(".main").unbind();
    }
});
```

nothing seems to work, thank you for taking the time.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what i did to fix it:

```
   var main = $(".main"),
   sbContainer = $("#sb-container"),
   sbContainerDiv = sbContainer.find("div");
   tblcontents = $('#tblcontents');
   tblcontentstwo = $('#tblcontents_2')



  function animate() { 
   sbContainerDiv.css({ 
       "transform": "rotate(0deg)",
           "-webkit-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
           "-ms-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
           "-moz-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
           "-o-transform": "rotate(0deg)"
   });

   main.animate({
       "right": "1%"
   }, "slow");
}

   function toggletwo() {

   var toggleStatetwo = true;
   $(tblcontents).on("click", function () {
       if (toggleStatetwo) {
           animate({
               "top": "15%"
           });
           main.fadeOut(1000);
       } else {
           animate();
           main.fadeIn(1000);
       }
       toggleStatetwo = !toggleStatetwo;
   });

 }

 function toggleone() {
   $(tblcontents).on("click", function () {
       animate({
           "top": "1%"
       });
       main.stop(true, true);
   });

 }

 $(window).resize(function () {
   if ($(window).width() < 960) {
       toggletwo();
       animate();
   } else {
       toggleone();
   }
 });


 if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   toggletwo();
 } else {
   toggleone();
}

 $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
       toggleone();
       animate();
   } else {

   }
 });
 var toggleState = true;
$('.toggle_div').on("click", function () {
   if (toggleState) {
       main.animate({
           "right": "50%"
       }, "slow");
   } else {
       main.animate({
           "right": "1%"
       }, "slow");
   }
   toggleState = !toggleState;
 });
```

Hope this helps anybody...